# Can't get Java3D going on ImageJ 3DViewer

Tags: macos, 3d, imagej, java-3d

OS: Mac OS 10.11.1

I installed ImageJ and was going to display the example image "flybrain.tif" using "3D Viewer" under Plugins -> 3D. However, the 3D viewer doesn't launch.

I searched around and realised that it could be a problem from java3d, so downloaded java3d from https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html. I placed the three *.jar from java3d under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib

and added the paths to the ~/.bash_profile.

The 3D viewer still doesn't start. Anything else I can try? Many thanks!

Comment: Use the Java3D version bundled with Fiji. The version you quote in your question is completely obsolete and ImageJ doesn't use the version bundled with OS X.

Comment: @gouessej Thanks! Could you please let me know which Fiji version you were referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar, not identical setup (Mac OS 10.11.2, jdk 1.8.0_66) and I am able to open the Fly Brain in 3D viewer using [Fiji](http://imagej.net/Fiji).

In Fiji, I [activated the update sites](http://imagej.net/How_to_follow_a_3rd_party_update_site) for ImageJ, Fiji, and 3D.

You might also try posting the question at the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have just installed Fiji and discovered that there's an issue with JOGL. /Users/TTZ/.ImageJ_3D_Viewer.props (No such file or directory)                   Exception in thread "J3D-Renderer-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path   Did you need to download and install JOGL separately, I wonder?

Comment: I have JOGL, j3dutils, and j3dcore in /Library/Java/Extensions, but they are old (2010). The Fiji "3D" update site also installs specialized versions of these jars in the Fiji.app folder -- see [this post for details](http://forum.imagej.net/t/java-3d-progress-and-next-steps/135). Maybe this will help resolve the issue?

Comment: @TTZ please see also yesterday's [news post on the ImageJ wiki](http://imagej.net/2015-12-22_-_The_road_to_Java_8). The 3D update site and the Java-8 update site are the same thing.

Comment: @TSwayne I installed the version from the link http://forum.imagej.net/t/java-3d-progress-and-next-steps/135 and got the following error message when I tried to rotate the 3D image.                        3D [dev] 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-pre11-daily-experimental daily

version = 1.6
nFrames = 1
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: detachAllImpl failed: FBO implementation fault, ...

Comment: @TTZ Do not use the version from that forum post anymore. Please use the Java-8 update site instead. See the [relevant news post](http://imagej.net/2015-12-22_-_The_road_to_Java_8).

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by downloading the fiji-jogl-java3d-20151006220121.zip file from http://forum.imagej.net/t/java-3d-progress-and-next-steps/135. The 3D viewer works and I am able to record the 3D video again. Thank you every one, @TSwayne @Jan-Eglinger @gouessej

Comment: The re-sizing function doesn't work though. I got this error message when I tried to resize the 3D image... `com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: detachAllImpl` failed: FBO implementation fault.  It seems to be a known problem [link](https://github.com/fiji/3D_Viewer/issues/15)

Comment: Do not use the version from that forum post anymore. Please use the Java-8 update site instead. See the [relevant news post](http://imagej.net/2015-12-22_-_The_road_to_Java_8). The resizing problem is a [known issue](https://github.com/fiji/3D_Viewer/issues/15).